# vsts-npm-auth exists with code 1, the input is not a valid Base-64 string

Tags: npm, .npmrc

I have configured my project to use private Azure DevOps feed through .npmrc file.

I have a .js script that does the following:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const npmrc_location = ...
const commands = 
[    
    'npm install vsts-npm-auth --registry https://registry.npmjs.com --always-auth false --no-save',    
    'vsts-npm-auth -R -C ' + npmrc_location
];

exec(commands.join('&&'), (error) => {    
    if (error) {        
       console.log(error)    
}});
```

When it first creates the .npmrc file under $env:USERPROFILE.npmrc file, everything is fine.

The documentation says that if the -F flag is "absent or false, an existing token in the target configuration file will only be replaced if it is near or past expiration." So re-running the script as part of the building step of my project should be fine.

However, there are times when I run into the following error when `'vsts-npm-auth -R -C ' + npmrc_location'` is executed:

> ```
> vsts-npm-auth v0.41.0.0:
> The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters..
> ```

My best guess is that it tries to read the content of .npmrc file.

Does anyone know why this can happen and what would be a good solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 62):

i think you might have run the vsts-npm-auth before and got token hiddenly stored within the .npmrc at your home dir and it`s not valid anymore, you might try to use -F to force fetching a new token.

Comment: Nothing like useless error messages. Thanks @Ahmed using -F worked for me

Comment: like a charm and leaves me feeling stupid. one would think i'd be used to it by now lol

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed It's working for me

Comment: Why can't i upvote twice ?

Answer (score 21):

@Ahmed has the right idea. I cannot comment on the answer, but in short you can run this to fetch the token:

`vsts-npm-auth -config <path_to_npmrc_file> -F`

Answer (score 1):

If this helper is defined in the npm script which is more convenient like below,

```json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "start:dev": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "registryAuth": "vsts-npm-auth -config .npmrc"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  }
}
```

Force token acquisition can be done by passing argument through `run`

```
npm run registryAuth -- -F
```

Reference - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vsts-npm-auth

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the main **.npmrc** file was corrupted. I fixed it with following steps

1. delete (or rename to .npmrc_backup) the .npmrc file located in route C:\Users<*someuser*> or equivalent linux path
2. run your **vsts-npm-auth** command again